# Duda sobre la función atoi

Tags: c, funciones, matemáticas

Disculpen mi ignorancia.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
    char A[10];
    int I = -1, Aux = 0;
    printf("Ingrese caracter ");
    do
    {
        I++;
        if (I >= 0)
        {
            for (int J = 0; J < I; J++)
            {
                printf("%c", A[J]);
            }
        }
        A[I] = getch();
        system("cls");
        while (A[I] != '1' && A[I] != '2' && A[I] != '3' && A[I] != '4' && A[I] != '5' && A[I] != '6' && A[I] != '7' && A[I] != '8' && A[I] != '9' && A[I] != '0' && A[I] != 13)
        {
            printf("Dato invalido\n");
            for (int J = 0; J < I; J++)
            {
                printf("%c", A[J]);
            }
            A[I] = getch();
            system("cls");
        }
    } 
    while (A[I] != 13);
    Aux = atoi(A);
    printf("Numero %d", Aux);
    scanf(" ");
}
```

Lo que intento hacer en este codigo es que cuando el usuario ingrese un valor que no sea numerico, le siga volviendo a pedir un valor numerico.

Una vez que todos los valores sean numericos, convertirlos en int y así poder utilizarlo en futuros calculos.

Lo que hago para que el codigo sepa cuando parar de ingresar, sea cuando el usuario ingrese ENTER.

**Mi duda es si la funcion atoi va a tomar el valor ENTER.**

Disculpen, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, el atoi no tomará enter como un salto de linea.
Si te interesa, hay una función de la librería ctype que hace la comprobación de si un carácter es alfabético o numérico.

```
while(aux[i]){
    if(!isalpha(aux[i])){
    printf("ERROR: El nombre no puede contener números"); break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Lo que hace ese código es validar un nombre, si contiene caracteres devuelve un error (la función comprueba carácter por carácter y la librería ctype tiene funciones isalpha(carácter) o isdigit(carácter) que devuelven verdadero si cumple la condición de ser alfabético o dígito respectivamente).